# every 5th AD query is very slow, why?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, ldap

I’m binding a FreeNAS box to AD for student logins to SMB mounts. That all works fine.

I have a bash script that runs on the FreeNAS to build an index.html page pointing to a subdirectory of each student’s home directory, where they can put finished coding projects on the web for public view. That works too.

The script does an AD lookup for each user on the FreeNAS, and only adds them to the index.html file if they are a student (ie, member of the `CN=students` group):

```
ldapsearch -Q -LLL cn=[someuser] ObjectCategory:CN=Person memberOf
```

Here’s the weird part. About 80% of the time, the AD lookup happens instantly. Every fifth lookup, it takes 75 seconds to complete. I’ve written a script to test this and the pattern is quite reproducible. Almost invariably, every 5th lookup takes exactly 75 seconds, and it doesn’t matter if you look up the same name 5 times or different ones.

If I do an `ldapsearch` immediately in the command line:

```
ldapsearch -LLL cn=someuser
```

and I do it repeatedly, every 5th repetition it's slow. If I abort the slow query by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, the next time I do it it's fast again.

I don’t run the AD server, and the AD admin doesn’t know why this would be happening. Any clues?

DNS is configured correctly both ways AFAIK -- or at least, everything else about the setup seems to work (users can log into the FreeNAS using AD credentials, and that happens reasonably fast). All clocks are in sync too.

Comment: How many AD servers do you have? How many sites?

Comment: there is a cluster of AD servers, 5 I think, for a college campus with something like 5000 users

Comment: hmmmm, 5 servers, every 5th query is slow. Wonder if there's a way to find out which of the servers executed the query?

Comment: With 5 servers, i would use the -H option to ldapsearch and test each one individually to see which server is failing.

Comment: not sure how to do that. When I host lookup the name of the AD domain, I get 5 IP addresses back. Does each of those have its own LDAP URI?

Comment: Yea (also those address will change order each time you query) you can do `ldapsearch -H ldap[s]://<server_name>[:ldap_port] <your other options>`

Answer (score 3):

The 5th query is probably against a domain controller in another site (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782048%28v=ws.10%29.aspx, this is for 2003 AD but still valid).

With a query like this:

```
ldapsearch -h domaincontroller -LLL -s sub -x -W -b cn=configuration,dc=your,dc=domain -Z -D "cn=youruser,ou=container,dc=your,dc=domain" "objectclass=subnet" cn siteobject
Enter LDAP Password: 
dn: CN=172.20.4.0/24,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.20.4.0/24
siteObject: CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.20.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.20.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.30.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.30.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=London,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.19.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.19.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.18.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.18.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.21.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.21.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=New York,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.23.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.23.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.17.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.17.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain

dn: CN=172.31.0.0/16,CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
cn: 172.31.0.0/16
siteObject: CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain
```

you can see in this network we have the standard 'Default-First-Site-Name' object, plus the New York and London sites.

Once you know where your freenas host is inside the AD sites ip ranges, then you can query the dns servers for the ldap hosts in that site. The query is like this for the london site:

```
dig -t srv _ldap._tcp.london._sites.your.domain +short
0 100 389 dc05.your.domain.
0 100 389 dc03.your.domain.
0 100 389 dc04.your.domain.
```

And in the answer section you shall see the different ldap hosts for that site. So you can use just those ones.

Comment: Thanks, it's all one site (one campus) though one of the five servers is unreachable .... so I'm thinking that's where the issue is

Comment: that should be it then. Look in the ldap client options to lower the timeout of the queries then, it should be possible to switch faster to another domain controller if the one it's trying is not responding on a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0):

sure enough, one of the five servers wasn't responding (don't know whether it's offline, or it doesn't exist, or what .... the AD admin will have to deal with that.)

I rewrote the script so that it only queries the four good servers (randomly selecting which one every time) and now it executes instantly!

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that `ldapsearch` is broken and dysfunctional in that way when working with Active Directory :-)